# Get cyrillic text from postgres table in terminal (linux)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

PostgreSQL version: 13.4

CLIENT_ENCODING:    UTF8

I am using ubuntu terminal to connect to a remote Postgres database. Due to security and other reasons, this is the only way available (client company provides only this option). When I select data from a table which includes cryllic text fields what I see is this:

`<D0><BD><D0><B0> <D0><BE><D1><84><D0><B8><D1><86><D0><B8><D0><B0><D0><BB><D1><8C><D0><BD><D1><8B><D1><85> <D0><B4><D0><BE><D0><BA><D1><83><D0><BC><D0><B5><D0><BD><D1><82><D0><B0><D1><85>`

Numbers and latin letters are shown correctly.

How can I get cryllic text as it is, or decode this output?

Comment: Instead of using the terminal, you can spin up an SSH tunnel and then use any nice looking UI to connect to the database. I use Squirrel SQL client over SSH tunnels all the time.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks for your suggestion. Yes we were able to connect it to Beekeeper through a SSH tunnel